# unable to bind data with dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am making an application in asp.net using C# which contains drop down list.Now I don't want to write same code for fetching same data from database.I am try this code but it's not working

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable DT = sel_obj.select_Dept_Name();
        departmentDrop.DataSource = DT;
        departmentDrop.DataMember = "Department_Name";
        departmentDrop.DataBind();
    }
 public DataTable select_Dept_Name()
    {
        module c = new module();
        c.DB_Connection();

        if (c.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            c.con.Close();
            c.con.Open();
        }

        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        string QRY = "";
        QRY = "SELECT Department_Name FROM Department_Master";
        SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(QRY, c.con);
        DA.Fill(DS);
        DataTable DT = DS.Tables[0];
        return DT;
    }
```

Comment: `not working` is not a correct question. Please be more specified about the problem you're facing

Comment: add `departmentDrop.ValueMember = "Department_Name"` and `departmentDrop.DataBind();` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call "DataBind()" function. You need to also make sure that your table contains data to bind with dropdown list.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        DataTable DT = sel_obj.select_Dept_Name();
        departmentDrop.DataSource = DT ;
        departmentDrop.DataTextField = "Department_Name";
        departmentDrop.DataValueField = "Department_Name";
        departmentDrop.DataBind();
        }
    }
```